# Should a headless desktop client web-service client be a dynamically-registered OIDC client - or something else?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

My set-up has the following:

- This is a multi-tenant system, so the set of User Claims includes `tenant_id` which uniquely identifies the tenant that the user belongs to.
- An IdentityServer4-based web-service (this provides OAuth2/OpenID Connect services): `https://identity.example.com`.
- A separate web-service (RESTful web-api): `https://random-number-generator-service.example.com`.
- A headless program (Windows Service) that runs on on-premises computers at many locations: `RandomNumberConsumer.exe`. This program makes use of `random-number-generator-service` in the context of a `tenant_id` so a user needs to authenticate at some point somehow but otherwise the program does not care about the user's details, only the user's tenant's details.

I understand this means that both `random-number-generator-service` **and** `RandomNumberConsumer.exe` are "clients".

Within IdentityServer all client software must be registered (either statically as a hardcoded list of `Client` object instances or with some kind of dynamic registration using a database to store client details. Obviously `random-number-generator-service` will have a static registration, but how should `RandomNumberConsumer.exe` also be registered?

Some options:

1. Add a new web-application that users can login-to using a web-browser and register their `RandomNumberConsumer.exe` installation (which adds a new `Client` registration in `identity.example.com`'s Client database, complete with a client secret) then the user manually copies and pastes the client secret into `RandomNumberConsumer.exe`'s configuration file. The internal database maps each client registration with the `tenant_id`. This has the advantage of allowing individual client access revocation, but requires the user to perform manual configuration steps which are undesirable.
2. Have a single Client registration for `RandomNumberConsumer.exe` without any Client Secret, but the Client application needs a GUI component with which it can authenticate the user and it stores the user's associated `access_token` and `refresh_token` in its local configuration. This has the advantage of having a much simpler user-experience (as the user would open a `RandomNumberConsumerConfiguration.exe` program which then opens the web-browser to access the authentication page and gets the data using a `redirect_uri` with a temporary `localhost` or custom URI scheme value) but it means the `RandomNumberConsumer.exe` instance is associated with an individual human user when we only want it to be associated with the tenant instead.

Are there any other approaches that could be used instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every instance of a client should have it's own id. `random-number-generator-service` should have one id (even when it runs in a web farm).

`RandomNumberConsumer.exe` is installed on different machines outside the domain, so should have a unique id per installation.

A client has nothing to do with a user as the *sub* claim is missing. The only time the client includes the *sub* claim is when it acts on behalf (and with consent) of the user. This can be the case for `random-number-generator-service`, but not for `RandomNumberConsumer.exe` where there is no user interaction (as it is a Windows Service) and consent is not needed as it is given when the user requested the installation.

When you are talking about a Windows Service then it is inevitable to configure the service. You can however implement configuration steps in the installer. So instead of having to build UI or hacking a configuration file, you can take the following approach:

1. User requests an installation of the program. When approved a client is created and attached to the tenant (ClientClaims), based on the user.
2. The user starts the download of the installer and receives the id/secret (on screen, email).
3. User starts the installation and in one of the steps the user has to enter the id/secret. This is acceptable since it is quite common when installing software.

This has the advantages you want and takes minimal steps from the user.

If the service has more configuration options and you want to give the user a UI to maintain the options then add a configuration program to the installer. This is quite common for routers and printers. There is no need for the user to login as it runs local (localhost website). You can add a link for the browser as shortcut.

Comment: As the `RandomNumberConsumer.exe` installation is associated with a User's tenant account, how do I associate claims with the client account when there's no Identity or `User`? Only a User can have Claims - if the client successfully authenticates with `random-number-service` then the service has no way of knowing what Tenant account the Client is associated with.

Comment: The client can also have claims. The download should only be available for users, so the page has to be secured to make sure the user is logged in. From the User claims you can read the tenant_id and add it to the client as claim.